# How to repair, with some degree of strength, the outside corner of an internal doorway

Tags: walls, repair, security

I have a security gate that was mounted to a door frame, not by myself. Unfortunately there were two significant problem: it was mounted very close to the corner, and of more urgent concern, the wrong drill and raw plugs combination was used, so the gate was falling out of the wall.

Perhaps more unfortunately , I tried to repair it myself by using bigger raw plugs and bolts... It seems the bolts went to the sides of the raw plugs and put pressure on the wall, ultimately cracking it apart, as you can see in the picture

[image: cracked wall]

The simple question, is how can I repair this, and preferably with enough strength to remount the security gate?

(It doesn't need to withstand enormous force, this is a security gate primarily to satisfy insurance companies, but I guess it should survive a good kick or someone thumping into it if possible.)

Comment: Is that brown cement or plaster, or some sort of fake-wood product?

Comment: The wall looks like it's some pretty fragile stuff.  Any chance you could cut out a notch and dowel in something stronger like concrete, to which you could attach your gate (could even embed internally-threaded fasteners in the concrete)?  Can you also provide a pic or two with more context?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing *what* it's made of, if you remove the screws and apply any decent epoxy (skip the 5-minute stuff) to the broken part and then secure it in place until the epoxy cures you should be able to drill out the holes and try again.

Presumably you need larger holes and larger plugs to properly accommodate the larger screws. Or you have the holes full of epoxy and re-drill them for the smaller screws, or perhaps some *longer* plugs and screws and deeper holes if the frame gets thicker away from the door, as it appears to.

Comment: Good thought - I'd carve out a trapezoid using a multi-tool with the narrow end at the surface so the epoxy would really have a good chance of staying in. And it's probably realistically going to need metal reinforcement to actually stand up to any sort of good thump.

Comment: Also, consider mounting more toward the center so you're not putting pressure right onto the wall surface, but mounting it into whatever door framing you've got.